# False Teeth Made of Obsidian?

Tags: materials, medicine, body-modification

How feasible would a set of false teeth made of obsidian be? Assume technology has to be no more advanced than the mid 1800s.

If implausible for full time use, would such a set be practical enough to wear most of the time but remove/switch when eating? (and would early dentistry be capable of making that kind of false teeth?)

Answer (score 4):

**Obsidian dentures are plausible**

- Obsidian was chiseled down to a few centimeters of precision [millennia ago](https://phys.org/news/2011-12-oldest-obsidian-bracelet-reveals-amazing.html)
- Vulcanite rubber dentures were [invented in the 1840s](https://bda.org/museum/collections/teeth-and-dentures/vulcanite-dentures) and would provide a suitable base for obsidian teeth
- Vulcanite is also cheaper than any alternative available at that time, such as gold (though gold gums supporting obsidian dentures would look VERY interesting)

It's unclear exactly how precisely obsidian could be carved in this time period, or how long obsidian dentures would last. The limiting factor is probably the strength of the rubber, but it is supposed to be durable. I imagine your character's dentures would still have to be taken out and cleaned frequently, but for plot purposes, you can omit this (when do books ever show characters using basic hygiene unless it serves the plot?)

Answer (score 4):

Reality check: **Totally Feasible**

You could also go the obsidian dental implant route. Our distant ancestors were not above crafting [false teeth](https://www.archaeology.org/news/2143-140528-gaul-false-tooth) from iron, ivory and, of all things, cadaver teeth, and [jamming the piece](http://www.empowereddoctor.com/2018/01/11/the-history-of-dental-implants-part-one/) up into someone's jaw.

Really, not a whole lot different than a modern implant, when you get down to it.

Comment: As the recipient of multiple implants, most installed by a professional dentist and one installed by a student dentist (during a time when I didn’t have health care), let me assure you that there’s a great difference between dental implant and a guy just jamming something into one’s jaw! ;-)

Comment: @SRM -- From the other side of the process, let me assure you it is precisely a guy jamming something into your jaw! White coat and sterile tools notwithstanding! ;-Þ